# Como descargar un archivo local que esta en Otro disco Local con Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp

Tengo el sig codigo :

```
<button onclick="javascript:descargarZip(this.value)" value="<%=sArchivoZip%>"><img src="./IMG/icons/mail-arrow-down-icon.png" /></button>
```

el cual  llama a una funcion de descarga en js:

```
function descargarZip(val)
```

{

```
 var url='file://G://Pibexpress//logipc//'+ val;
  // location.href= url;

 window.open(url, 'Download');
```

}

*El problema es que el archivo NO esta dentro del IIS (C://inetpub//Wwwroot/pagina/pagina.asp) donde se encuentra el asp; sino que esta en otra unidad como ejemplo: G://carpeta/archivos/archivo.zip.

El navegador me indica esto.

FIREFOX
Error: Access to 'file:///G://carpeta//archivos//archivo.zip' from script denied

CHROME
Not allowed to load local resource:file:///G://carpeta//archivos//archivo.zip'.

Y por ende no puedo descargar el archivo, si alguien conoce la solucion se los agradeceria mucho.

GRACIAS POR SU APOYO =)

Answer (score 1):

Pasa lo siguiente, JavaScript se ejecuta al lado del cliente/browser, cuando le dices que intente descargar ese archivo lo buscará en el equipo donde se está ejecutando.
Lo que puedes hacer es configurar el archivo o la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo en el IIS para que sea accesible y direccionarlo por http. (por cierto, debe ser el mismo dominio o te dará problemas de CORS). 
Una segunda es que programes algo al lado del server con C# o vb (ejemplo) que lea y despliegue el archivo.

Comment: va que va,  muchas gracias. Saludos